# use different configuration xml in ear for deployment of wmq.jmsra.rar

Tags: xml, maven, jboss, jms, ibm-mq

i have to use the wmq jmsra rar and for that i have updated the standalone XML to configure  resource adapter for the same.
i don't want to touch standalone XML file but the want to update the existing standalone XML  during deployment of war or need some configuration file in ear itself to configure the wmq jmsra rar resource adapter.

Comment: Can you explain the question in a better way and with others details?

Comment: ok. for using WMQ jms rar i have updated the standalone xml in jboss, but in longer run i want to dynamically change the standalone xml in jboss for inclusion of resource adapter.